# Azure AD Authentication seems to be skipped in my ASP.Net Core 2.2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I have an empty ASP.Net Core application and I'd like to have Azure AD authentication invoked. However my "milldeware" seems always ignore authentication. Please help me to figure out the root cause. Thank you.
My appliaction is in .Net Core 2.2

Below is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("AzureAD", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddRouting();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouter(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapGet(string.Empty, HomeMiddleware);
                routes.MapGet("test", TestMiddleware);
            });
        }
```

Below are some middlewares I'd like to routes.

```
        [Authorize]
        private Task HomeMiddleware(HttpContext context)
        {
            return context.Response.WriteAsync($"control, User: {context.User.Identity.Name}");

        }

        [Authorize]
        private Task TestMiddleware(HttpContext context)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var writer = new HttpResponseStreamWriter(context.Response.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
                writer.Write("test");
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Write("another test");
                writer.Flush();
            });
        }
    }
```

Seems [Authorize] doesn't work for my 'middleware'. the **context.User.Identity.Name** returns nothing to me and it doesn't redirect me to AzureAD authentication page.

Comment: You shouldn't be using .NET Core 2.2 in new projects. It went out of support 3 years ago. The current LTS version is .NET (Core) 6, supported until 2024

Answer (score 0):

Update: net core 2.2 My bad.

I'm not sure the authorizeattribute works out of controllers. But I'd give it a try specifying the name of the policy like:

```
[Authorize("AzureAD")]
```

If that works but you don't want to specify the policy every time, I've seen in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2 there should be a `FallbackPolicy` property like the DefaultPolicy in 3.1:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

---

This is for 3.1.

First, you wan't to setup a default policy not to create just a policy. For that use

```
 auth.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder
     .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
     .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
```

Second, you want to add the Authorization middleware, not only the authentication one.

```
 app.UseAuthentication();

 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.UseRouter(routes =>
 ...
```

Without this middleware Authorize attributes have no effect afaik

You can also leave the policy as it is and

A) use it on the `app.UseAuthorization()` call, I belive there's a overload to choose the default policy name there.

B) leave it being a named not default policy and use `[Authorize("<policyName>")]` on your endpoints.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm in .net core 2.2, there is no app.UseAuthorization() and AddDefaultPolicy().

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry I see I missed a couple of details from your question, I've updated my answer. Anyway, December 23, 2019 was this version end of life. It's been 2 and something years now. It's time.

Comment: @Narv0007 that's a bigger problem. .Net Core 2.2 went out of support a long time ago. The current Long-Term Support version is .NET (Core) 6.0. The previous one, .NET Core 3.1, goes out of support in December 2022. Package developers (including Microsoft, Azure) have no obligation to keep supporting .NET Core 2.x

Comment: Thank you @Pablo Recalde , but the attribute [Authorize("AzureAD")] does not work. And 
 FallbackPolicy is only availabile for .net core 3.0 and higher versions. The reson we use .net core 2.2 is that we want the application can be run in both .net core and .net framework platforms, and I'm not the one who make the decision:)